# Has anyone used the Alamy export plugin in Lightroom with any sucess?

Tags: lightroom-3

I'm evaluating the [Alamy Export Lightroom Plug-in](http://www.lightroom-plugins.com/AlamyIndex.php) with Lightroom 3, but it doesn't seem to do anything -- If I attempt to export, I get a log that says "[My filename] Test Mode, nothing done (1.88 Mb)". I was also expecting it to integrate as a publish service, so I wonder if it's set up wrong?

Comment: If there are better plugins for doing this, then please feel free to suggest them...

Comment: For reference, Alamy don't currently have plans to do their own plugin: http://twitter.com/#!/AlamyContribs/status/29080745112

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of this plug-in.

First, just for reference the "Test Mode" in the logfile is controlled by a tickbox in the exporter. It's intended to let you run through the export and upload procedure without actually having to submit something to Alamy. It was useful to me during testing, and I left it there just in case people wanted to e.g. check the resulting exported images for themselves before submitting for the first time.

> Either way, it seems like you are rather gimped until you pay for a license.

Not at all - the free version works entirely as the full (paid) version does, including uploading and downloading from Alamy, except that it will stop after the first three images. There wouldn't be much point in a trial that didn't let you try things out!

Unless, of course, you mean "unable to use the software, for free, for ever, with no restrictions". In which case you are, indeed, gimped.

Cheers,
Jim

Comment: I'd been trying to Export using the right click -> Export -- can these settings be changed (or even removed, as you don't get the option to change out of test mode)

Answer (score 2):

I'm using it with no problems. The trial version is fully functional, just for a limited number of images (at least it was when I tried it some time ago).

I've also found queries answered quickly by the developer (using the contact page on the website)

Answer (score 1):

> I'd been trying to Export using the
>   right click -> Export -- can these
>   settings be changed (or even removed,
>   as you don't get the option to change
>   out of test mode)

Yes, you can change the settings. In fact, you absolutely *need* to change them. You'll need to export using the full dialog at least once though. The plugin comes with default settings "Presets" for each of the three export functions. You can remove these or edit them using the normal Lightroom functions in the Export dialog. Once you've done one export LR should remember the previously-used settings and use those in future. That will let you just use the "Export..." menu instead of the full dialog.

FYI I don't normally monitor other forums; if you post something and don't get an answer please remember the "Support" links on my website.

Cheers,
Jim

Comment: I appreciate your input here -- I was trying peer assistance without having to bother you first -- there's a lot of Lightroom users here, and I admit that I'm a new convert to it, and trying to streamline my whole workflow which is why I'm evaluating your plugin.